# Output A Float Without Zero Before Decimal Point

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm wondering how a float that has a zero followed by a decimal followed by numbers like this:

`0.45`

...to ditch the zero that's in front of the decimal point like this:

`.45`

within a NSString using the `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` method using Objective C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly eliminate the leading `0` when formatting a floating point value using `stringWithFormat:` and `%f`. You will have to remove it yourself from the result:

```
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", 0.45];
if ([result hasPrefix:@"0."]) {
    result = [result substringFromIndex:1];
}
```

But a better solution is to use `NSNumberFormatter`. Set `minimumIntegerDigits` to `0` to avoid the leading `0`.

```
NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
fmt.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
fmt.minimumInterDigits = 0;
NSString *result = [fmt stringFromNumber:@(0.45)];
```

This has the advantage of formatting the result properly for the user's locale (other than removing the leading 0).

It may best to avoid removing the leading 0. The output may be confusing to users.

Comment: It’s for a SpriteKit game. For the OS that I’m targeting, SpriteKit won’t allow label nodes to have font attributes so I have to create two labels: one with large font (the whole number portion) and one with small font (the decimal portion). Thanks for the response.